# How to start a BDD in test

Tags: rspec, cucumber

I want to develop a small feature in my rails app.How to start with it.Whether i need to go by cucumber features or by rspec itself

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of individual preference in most cases.  My personal approach is that if I am dealing with a customer requirement then Cucumber is an effective approach as it is generally more readable/understandable.  If I am developing for myself then rspec by itself is faster to get up an running and easier for me to control the build/test/refactor process.